# How do I destroy an ExtJS grid without affecting its store?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have an ExtJS store like so:

```
var dataStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({...});
```

I'm using it with a factory to get a GridPanel:

```
function CreateGrid(config) {
    return new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
        store: dataStore,
        ...
    })
};
```

Now, when I run this code:

```
new Ext.Window({
    closable: true,
    items: CreateGrid(),
}).show();
```

The first time I run it, the grid works fine. However, if I close the window and re-open another one, I can't sort the columns anymore, nor refresh the store.

I've pinpointed the issue down to the store, and whatever is happening to it when the grid is destroyed. If I change my `CreateGrid()` function to this instead:

```
function CreateGrid(config) {
    return new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
        store: new Ext.data.JsonStore({...}),
        ...
    }
};
```

It works perfectly fine, except I'm getting a new store each time instead of re-using the old one.

How do I fix this problem so that I can destroy the grid without messing up the store? The thought behind this is that I want to keep the store around in order to preserve the column sorting and filtering, but destroy the grid in order to save on memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the problem is. There's a bug with the Livegrid extension that messes up the underlying livegrid-specific store when the grid is closed.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is way late, but I destroy grids all the time in ExtJS 4 (3 too) and the stores are preserved.

What I have found is that if you give a store a storeId value, it is preserved (in ExtJS 3 it lasts until the DOM is cleared or Ext.StoreMgr.lookup( storeId ).destory() is called).

Answer (score 0):

You do not specify how you close the window (by calling the close method, or closing the window from UI), but perhaps you should *hide* it instead? Quoting ExtJS documentation:

> By default, the close header tool
>   destroys the Window resulting in
>   destruction of any child Components.
>   This makes the Window object, and all
>   its descendants unusable. To enable
>   re-use of a Window, use closeAction:
>   'hide'.

And about the closeAction config option specifically:

> This setting does not affect the close
>   method which will always destroy the
>   window. To programatically hide a
>   window, call hide.

Comment: Oops, I was using `Window` only as an easy way to test the problem. The `GridPanel` is actually in another `Panel`, and I'm using `Panel.remove()` to remove the grid.

Answer (score 0):

In your store, set `autoDestroy: false`.

Comment: By default it's false, and I didn't set it to true.

Answer (score 0):

> The thought behind this is that I want to keep the store around in order to preserve the column sorting and filtering, but destroy the grid in order to save on memory.

Is column sorting and filtering kept intrnally on the `GridPanel` object, or on the `Store` object? I'm not sure without digging into the src code. This might be your issue. Maybe you can achieve "remembering" the sort/filter in a cookie (see `Ext.state.Manager`).

You can also try just hiding the grid instead of removing it, as suggested by Tommi. If you only have this one grid, memory usage shouldn't be too bad.

One last thing to try: in your factory fn, create the grid and then *attach* the store to it using `grid.store = dataStore;`